# insert data with laravel Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a problem when i´m traying insert data in my DB. always return a message
`Array to string conversion` and i don´t know why. In other controller i have this code and it´s ok. And now i need to insert a data but i can´t

My actual code is:

```
public function insertarActuacion(){
    $fechaActual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $tiempoEmpleado = 0;
    $bono = \DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT codBono
                                  FROM bonos
                                  WHERE bonos.usuario = " . \Auth::user()->id));
    $tiempoRestante = 0;

    \DB::insert("INSERT INTO actuacion (fecha, tiempoEmpleado, usuario, bono, tiempoRestanteBono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ",
                                                                 [ $fechaActual, $tiempoEmpleado, \Auth::user()->id, $bono, $tiempoRestante ] );
}
```

thanks for help me

Comment: Please debug `$bono` before inserting, `$bono` is returning a object collection as far my knowledge. attach your debugged data with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question can actually already lay in the error message.

One of your inserted values is considered to be an array, but the code tries to cast it as a string, which causes the error.

Check which of your data is an array, and only get the value from it which you need.

Alternatively, if you don't know what data is an array, you can use `var_dump($var)`, which will tell you what the type is and what it's content is. Use that for debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

As you are inserting `$bono` is an array. you need to select the value as below.

```
$bono = \DB::table('bonos')->select('codBono')->where('usuario',\Auth::user()->id)->first();

$codBono = '';
if(!empty($bono)){
   $codBono = $bono->codBono;
}
```

Now insert this value.

```
\DB::insert("INSERT INTO actuacion (fecha, tiempoEmpleado, usuario, bono, tiempoRestanteBono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ",
                                                                 [ $fechaActual, $tiempoEmpleado, \Auth::user()->id, $codBono, $tiempoRestante ] );
```